# Having trouble joining two tables

Tags: sql, join

I am working with a tutorial and have followed everything as demonstrated.  The common field is warehouse_id, but the join command does not work for me.  I have deleted and retyped the code multiple times as well as compared it against the demo and can't figure it out.

```
select
    count( Distinct warehouse.state ) AS num_states

FROM
    `applied-primacy-364918.warehouse_orders.Orders`
    JOIN `applied-primacy-364918.warehouse_orders.Warehouse` warehouse ON
        orders.warehouse_id = warehouse.Warehouse_id

GROUP BY
    warehouse.state
```

I get an error:

> unrecognized name for orders; Did you mean order_id? referenced line 6
> Dataset = warehouse_orders

Tables are `warehouse_orders.Orders` and `warehouse_orders.Warehouse`

Comment: Pls add schema for these 2 tables, so we can see how it is created. 1 minor thing, I think you have not set Alias for Orders table.
Should be 
```
 ... FROM
``applied-primacy-364918.warehouse_orders.Orders`` orders
...
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Looks like your system is case-sensitive for object names, so `FROM \`Orders\`` is not the same as  the `orders`  in your `JOIN orders...` clause.

Comment: @Dai Google Cloud

Comment: @Jacky Thank you, I believe that worked.  Thank you!